# HTML email signature Gmail app adds extra space between every table

Tags: html, email, gmail, signature

I have a problem when I send an HTML email signature from MS Outlook.

The problem is that the signature adds extra white space between all the elements and content such as text and even the horizontal line below the name.

The code in my HTML file looks like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="date=no" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="address=no" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
  <title>Boating World</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    /*<![CDATA[*/

    /* Linked Styles */

    body {
        padding: 0 !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
        display: block !important;
        background: #ffffff;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: none
      }

    /*]]>*/
</style>
</head>
<body style="padding:0 !important; margin:0 !important; display:block !important; background:#ffffff; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none">
  <table width="500" height="180" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <tr>
      <td align="left" valign="top">
        <table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; padding:0; margin:0; font-weight:normal; width:500px; min-width:500px; margin:0" width="500">
              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <td style=" font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#002855; font-weight:bold; line-height:18px;">
                    Kind Regards
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td height="5" style="font-size: 0px; line-height: 5px;">&nbsp;
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#002855; font-weight:600; line-height:20px; text-transform:uppercase; font-stretch:semi-expanded;">
                    <!-- Write your name and surname here -->
                    ELZAAN STEENKAMP
                    <!-- End of name -->
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td height="10" style="font-size: 0px; line-height: 10px;">&nbsp;
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <td style="border: none; font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:left" height="1" bgcolor="#909090">
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <td height="5" style="font-size: 5px; line-height: 5px;">&nbsp;
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <table width="200" align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td height="22" style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#002c5c; font-weight:bold; line-height:20px;">T:
                          <span style="font-family:Arial; font-weight:100; color:#444444;">
                            <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:#444444; cursor:default;">
                              <!-- Write your landline telephone number here (Please type in same manner "+27 (0)21 418 0840”)  -->
                              +27 (0) 21 418 0840
                              <!-- end of telephone number -->
                            </a>
                          </span>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td height="22" style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#002c5c; font-weight:bold; line-height:20px;">C:
                          <span style="font-family:Arial; font-weight:100; color:#444444;">
                            <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:#444444; cursor:default;">
                              <!-- Write the cellphone number here (Please type in similar manner "+27 (0)82 000 0000)  -->
                              +27 (0) 83 400 3418
                              <!-- end of telephone number -->
                            </a>
                          </span>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td height="22" style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#002c5c; font-weight:bold; line-height:20px;">E:
                          <span style="font-family:Arial; font-weight:100; color:#444444;">
                            <!-- To put in your email address, you need to add it twice, once next to where it states mailto: and then below, be careful not to change anything other than the email name. -->
                            <a href="mailto:accounts@boatingworld.co.za" style="text-decoration:none; color:#444444; cursor:default;">
                              <!-- End of email address code -->
                             <!-- Write your email address here as well -->
                              accounts@boatingworld.co.za
                              <!-- End of email address -->
                            </a>
                          </span>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <!--[if mso]></td><td><![endif]-->
                    <table align="left" width="20" height="20" style="font-size:20px; line-height: 20px;">
                      <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <!--[if mso]></td><td><![endif]-->
                    <table width="200" align="left" style="display:inline-table;">
                      <tr>
                        <td style="line-height:10px">
                          <img src="https://www.boatingworld.co.za/email_signature/bw_logo.jpg" style="display:block"/>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <td height="5" style="font-size: 5px; line-height: 5px;">&nbsp;
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <td width="20" align="left">
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/boatingworld?v=info" style="text-decoration:none; border:none;">
                      <img src="https://www.boatingworld.co.za/email_signature/facebook.jpg" />
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td width="20" align="left">
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/BoatingWorld1" style="text-decoration:none; border:none;">
                      <img src="https://www.boatingworld.co.za/email_signature/twitter.jpg" />
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td width="20" align="left">
                    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/boating.world/" style="text-decoration:none; border:none;">
                      <img src="https://www.boatingworld.co.za/email_signature/instagram.jpg" />
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td width="20" align="left">
                    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/BoatingWorldSA1" style="text-decoration:none; border:none;">
                      <img src="https://www.boatingworld.co.za/email_signature/youtube.jpg" />
                    </a>
                  </td>
                    <td width="420" align="left">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
              </table>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                  <td height="5" style="font-size: 5px; line-height: 5px;">&nbsp;
                  </td>
                </tr>
                </table>    
              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                <td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#002855; font-weight: 600; line-height:18px; text-transform:uppercase;">
                  <a href="https://www.boatingworld.co.za/" style="text-decoration: none;">
                    <span style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#002855; font-weight:bold; line-height:18px; text-transform:uppercase;">
                      WWW.BOATINGWORLD.CO.ZA
                    </span>
                  </a>
                </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tested multiple solutions answered elsewhere on the internet on different forums but to no avail.

Please can someone assist with this as this is for a very important client.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I solved it by adding below styles for p tag.

```
p { margin-top: 1px; margin-bottom:1px; margin-left:1px; margin-right:1px; }
```